# Calculating angles of triangle at intersection with plane

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have a plane. This plane is either $z=a$, $y=a$ or $x=a$ ($a$ being any constant). I have a camera somewhere in the world in which this plane lies.

I look at a line on a plane parallel to the given plane. I know the length of this line, and the projection angle $\beta$ (the angle under which I look at it with my camera).

Is it possible to determine the distance to the endpoints of my line?

Below is a little drawing for clarification. The endpoints of the line have the same $x$, $y$ or $z$ coordinates as the line is parallel to the given plane.

[image: Clarification]

Comment: Short answer is no, you can't. As illustrated by your figure, you can completely study this in 2D. There are infinitely many ways to position your line segment to obtain the same "projection angle" $\beta$, and each of these ways will give you different distances to the endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I know the slope of the line segment? Eg. say it is parallel to the plane $z=10$, and its slope is such that it goes from $(x,y)$ to $(x+1,y-1)$ ($x$ and $y$ are not given but desired)?

Comment: If you do not know where the camera is, fixing the slope "in the universe" won't change much. You'd have to fix the slope "with respect to the camera". Since I don't really get what the context is, what you actually know, or want to achieve, it's difficult to answer that question.

Comment: Yeah it's a problem I've been stuck with for a long time now. I'm having a cube which I look at with a camera. Side lengths are given, I know the position and Euler angles of the camera. I know the cube is aligned in the world's raster. I then get an image, and I have extracted the edges of the cube from this image. I also know which side I'm looking at (upper side, left side, ...) - the how of this is irrelevant. Now I need to know the location of the cube. I have the angle of view (horizontal/vertical) of the camera too, that's why I know the 'projection angle' for each edge.

Comment: I don't really see how you managed to retrieve the "projection angle" from that, you may have used a different camera model than the one I have in mind... Anyway, I think the 2D version of your problem can be solved with all of what you claim to know, but the discrepancy between the camera models I'm familiar with, and your camera model, is disturbing.

Comment: Isn't the projection angle determined by the location on the 2D image, knowing the horizontal and vertical angle of view and the dimensions of the image itself?

Comment: Actually yes, those should be enough, I'm kinda rusty with these things.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to address the problem? Or any kind of lead? I thought, if you take a vector in a plane parallel to that of the line segment, in world coordinates. Let's say that vector has the same slope as the line segment. Then you can use a rotation matrix (based on the camera's Euler angles) to transform it to camera coordinates. Then you can calculate the angle that this rotated vector's makes with the line segment. And that will give you an angle with which you can determine the distance to one of the line's end points. Not sure if it's bad reasoning.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your approach in your last comment, but I do have an idea how to solve your problem. The problem with explaining it, is that I don't know the standard terminology to explain it in English, so I was kinda hoping someone else would do it. If you're in a hurry I can throw something together later. Otherwise I should look for an illustration (or make one) to clarify the things I need in my method, but I don't exactly have time for that right now.

Comment: I'm not sure what language you speak, I speak french and dutch if one of them's your preferred language. Otherwise yes I'm in a hurry, but I don't want to take any of your time.

Comment: By “aligned with the world’s raster” do you mean that the cube’s edges are parallel to the coordinate axes?

Comment: Yes that's it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't really work a lot with camera models, my terminology will probably be imprecise.

Let's call $O$ the "center of projection" of the camera. Since I don't know how you track your camera, the position of $O$ may not exactly be that of the camera, but working with $O$ makes everything simpler. Normally if you know your camera matrix, you can deduce the position of $O$ from that of the camera.

With that said, let $PQ$ be the line segment, and $H$ the affine plane through $O,P,Q$. Choose an arbitrary coordinate system in $H$ with origin $O$. If you can obtain the polar coordinates of $P(\rho_P,\theta_P),Q(\rho_Q,\theta_Q)$ in $H$, then you're done. From your description you already know how to obtain the $\theta$ angle coordinate for both points, and you also know the vector $\vec{PQ}$.

Let $\mathbf u(\theta)$ denote the unit vector parallel to $H$ with angle $\theta$ in $H$. By definition $\vec{OP}=\rho_P\mathbf u(\theta_P)$ and
$\vec{OQ}=\rho_Q\mathbf u(\theta_Q)$. Because $\vec{PQ}$ is parallel to $H$, there exists some angle $\varphi$ such that $\vec{PQ}=a\mathbf u(\varphi)$, where $a$ denotes the side length of the cube. With the information you have, you should be able to compute (one of) the value(s) of $\varphi$.

From there you can establish a system of equation to obtain $\rho_P,\rho_Q$ from the other parameters $a,\theta_P,\theta_Q,\varphi$.
Using $\vec{PQ}=\vec{OQ}-\vec{OP}$ you can express the square of the length $PQ$ in two ways, which yield
$$ a^2=\rho_P^2+\rho_Q^2-2\rho_P\rho_Q\cos(\theta_P-\theta_Q)$$
Similarly you can compute the scalar product $\vec{OQ}.\vec{OP}$ in two ways which yield
$$\rho_P\rho_Q\cos(\theta_P-\theta_Q)=\rho_P^2+a\rho_P\cos(\theta_P-\varphi)$$
Under the (reasonable) assumption that $\rho_P\neq 0$, you can inject the second equation into the first, and you will obtain $\rho_Q$ or $\rho_P$ by solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: Thanks a great deal ...

Comment: Reread what I wrote, right now the most complicated part to me is to compute $\varphi$... If you're stuck with that, I could probably give you more details about that, but tomorrow.

Comment: I managed to get something to work, and want to try your method asap to see if it's better (mine is the one I described above, which is relatively simple but I don't trust it). In any case, I wanted to thank you for the help you provided.